# Alter Column to add CHECK on POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a movie list table:

> create table my_movies(   movie_name char(100) NOT NULL,  star_rating
> int NOT NULL)

The following is my table below:

[image]

How do I ***alter*** the column **star_rating** to ensure that it ***ONLY ACCEPTS*** a star rating from 0 to 5 when inserting?

I want to alter the column star_rating so that it does not accept negative integers or integers over 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check constraint as [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html)

```
alter table my_movies
   add constraint star_rating_valid check (star_rating >= 0 AND star_rating < 6);
```

Comment: Yes thanks @LaurenzAlbe response updated